# Conversão de byte[] para imagem retornando null

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, http-request

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile que enviar fotos do aplicativo para o servidor, feito em springboot. Ao receber a requisição com a imagem, via json, tento fazer a conversão de String para ImageIO. Porem, na conversão ele retorna null. Por algum motivo a conversão nao esta acontecendo e nao salvo a imagem.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/paciente")
public void paciente(@RequestBody String foto) throws IOException {

    try {

        byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(foto.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Encoded retorna >" + encoded)
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded);
        System.out.println("URL retorna >" + input);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
        System.out.println("IMAGE retorna >" + image);
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:/Users/carlo/Downloads/SisCAF/images/myImage1.jpg"));
        System.out.println("image created");

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

A saída:
Encoded retorna >[B@7646546e
URL retorna >java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1b7a9dc1
IMAGE retorna >null

Comment: pq você chama esse encodedBase64?

Comment: até onde eu sei esse `Base64.encodeBase64` está transformando essa foto em base64. tenta utilizar assim: `byte[] encoded = Base64.decode(foto);`